# Predicting houseprice: is it okay to use a constant (int) to indicate "unknown"

Tags: machine-learning, nan

I have a dataset and am trying to predict houseprices. Several variables (#bedrooms, #bathrooms, area, ...) use the constants 0 or -1 to indicate "not known". Is this good practice?

Dropping these values would result in the loss of too much data. Interpolation does not seem like a good option, especially since there are cases where multiple of these values are unknown and they are relatively highly correlated to each other.

Taking the mean of the column to substitute these values with would not work seeing as all houses are fundamentally different.

Does anyone have advise on this?

Answer (score 0):

Totally depends on what ML algorithm you want to use. Some can handle null values for missing data and others can't.

Usually interpolating/predicting these missing values is a reasonable idea. You could run another algorithm first to predict the missing values based on your available data and then run a second algorithm for the housing price prediction.